# 'Ruby on Rails' how to write test cases for Oauth2 Provider Doorkeeper configuration code written in config/initializer/doorkeeper.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I am using Doorkeeper gem as Oauth2 provider in my app. I am writing test cases for configuration done in config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb file as per my requirement. My config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb
file is as per below.I am authenticating resource_owner depends on session[:user_id] if it exists or otherwise redirecting to login page to authenticate resource_owner. This code executes well in development environment and getting session[:user_id] values but not in test environment.

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use.
  # Currently supported options are :active_record, :mongoid2, :mongoid3, :mongo_mapper
  orm :active_record

  # if no scope was requested, this will be the default
  default_scopes :public

  # other available scopes
  optional_scopes :admin, :write

  # This block will be called to check whether the resource owner is authenticated or not.
  resource_owner_authenticator do #|routes|
    #fail "Please configure doorkeeper resource_owner_authenticator block located in #{__FILE__}"
    # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
    # Example implementation:
    # User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url
      @user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(login_url(return_to: request.fullpath))
  end
end
```

I am using oauth2 Client in test case to simulate requests to oauth2 provider authorization end points in my provider app and setting client connection adapter to Rack.

```
@client = OAuth2::Client.new(@application.uid, @application.secret, :site => "http://127.0.0.1:3000") do |b|
    b.request :url_encoded
    b.adapter :rack, Rails.application
end
```

Is there any other way to simulate request and writing test cases for doorkeeper configuration or Am I committing any mistakes here?